# The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services. at FirebaseAppError

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am learning to use Firebase Cloud Function and I am following Firebase's official tutorial video for [Learn JavaScript Promises (Pt.1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA)

When I run a local server and  go to the HTTP link I get

Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

I tried finding the solution but couldn't find anywhere. I got some vaguely related question but for javascript and my code is in typescript. I did add the suggested syntax in both .js and .ts file

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

But still, I get the same error

Here is my index.tcs.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

// Start writing Firebase Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

export const getVoucher = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const promise = admin.firestore().doc('/voucher/Eg2AtnGmKmX8Y0vBZiBG').get()
    const p2 = promise.then(snapshot=>{
        const data = snapshot.data()
        response.send(data)
    })
    p2.catch(error => {
        //Handlle the error
        console.log('error: '+error)
        response.status(500).send(error)
    })
});
```

The function works as intended when deployed to firebase tho.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should just call `admin.initializeApp()` at the global scope of your code.  Don't pass any parameters to accept the default service account, which should have permission to read and write your Cloud Firestore database.

Comment: Global Scope would be after after import? Sorry, I am very new to this

Comment: Any place that's not inside a function or other block with curly braces, where you typically don't indent.

Comment: Can you please explain what  

"Don't pass any parameters to accept the default service account, which should have permission to read and write your Cloud Firestore database." means? I am getting This error now "  error: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information." and seems it is related to the service account related issue.

Comment: Also, the function works correctly if I deploy it to firebase so the error is only in the local server only.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the emulator.  This means updating the global firebase-tools module.

Comment: I did "npm install -g firebase-tools"  and it updated the package but I am still getting the same error.  I am sorry, I am just so new to all this and can't just figure out what i am missing.

Comment: Today, this works for running on production, but on local I0m successfully using this: ```admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'localhost:8080',
});```

Answer (score 31):

word of advice, sometimes this comes even if you initialized the app properly, at that point just check whether your db instance is placed inside the function not global.

#nodejs

```
var db = admin.database();//inside function
```

Answer (score 13):

This might sound like crazy, But I had the same issue. Then I've changed my "admin.initializeApp();" place like below. Then it works.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//put here.
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

const firebaseConfig = {
// config data
};

const firebase = require('firebase');

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to initialize app admin.initializeApp() before you use firestore or any other feature.

Answer (score 2):

i am use typescript, a pattner singleton, because admin.initializeApp(); needs a only instance

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
export default class firebaseDAO {

    private static _intance: firebaseDAO;
    db: any;
    private constructor() {

        admin.initializeApp();
        this.db = admin.firestore();
    }

    public static get instance() {
        return this._intance || (this._intance = new this());
    }

    // iniciar un metodo
    start() {
    }
}
```

create a DAO

```
import firebaseDAO from '../database/firebase.dao';

constructor(){
    this.db =  firebaseDAO.instance.db;
}

async getPacientes() {
    try {
        const userQuerySnapshot = await this.db.collection('pacientes').get();
        const users: any[] = [];
        userQuerySnapshot.forEach(
            (doc: any) => {
                users.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    data: doc.data()
                });
            }
        );
        this.response.resultado=users;
        return  this.response;
    } catch (error) {
        this.response.resultado=null;
        return  this.response;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what actually solved my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error because of calling `getFirestore()` before `admin.initializeApp()`

So I changed the order as below, and it worked.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = require('express')();
const firebase = require('firebase');    

// service account file custom for serve    
var serviceAccount = require("serviceAccount.json"); // for deploying you need to delete it

// admin credential for localhost or emulator
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "database_url"
});

// Firebase SDK configuration        
const config ={
    //firebase config
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
    
const db = admin.firestore();
```

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem by initializing the app directly after importing the firebase-admin

before

```
import * as algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { setFirstActivity } from './core/activities/helpers';
import { sendFCMWhenMsaHasBeenCreated } from './core/fcm';

// here is the issue
const project = admin.initializeApp();
import FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
import Timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp;
```

result [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XeVX.png)

after

```
import * as algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
// here is the solution
const project = admin.initializeApp();
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { setFirstActivity } from './core/activities/helpers';
import { sendFCMWhenMsaHasBeenCreated } from './core/fcm';


import FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
import Timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp;
```

result after deploying [successful result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuvQO.png)

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a performance argument to have the admin initializeApp within the function and not global scope.

You keep a global boolean var that you can use to decide whether your specific function needs to initialize.

Here's a great YouTube video on this topic by Firebase that's well worth a watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM

Example:

GLOBAL:

```
let isSpecificFunctionAdminInitialised = false;
```

WITHIN FUNCTION:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
if (!isSpecificFunctionAdminInitialised) {
  admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
  isSpecificFunctionAdminInitialised = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running the initialization before even importing `functions`

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Created file with utils, and there initialized firestor and storage.
Solved by moving app initialization before import:

```
initializeApp();
import { utils } from "./utils/utils"
```